# Framework 7 : Swipeable Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, html-framework-7

I am working on the application that consists of several tabs. I want to call my function whenever the `swipe` event occurs. 
Right now, I am using the `on-click` event handler for each tab. But I want to populate the screen on `swipe/tab` active.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a Framework7 function for that, but you can use the scroll handler on the `toolbar-inner` class as long as it is the responsible about making the horizontal scroll:

```
$$(".toolbar-inner").scroll(function() { 
    // your action here
});
```

Use the latest version of the framework also.

Comment: I used this solution:    $$('#ID').on('show', function () {
    // Your Function Here
}); It works with the swipe-able tabs.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.